# pyplot imshow() return for loop with multiple subplots

Tags: loops, matplotlib, imshow

```
data.shape
(800, 49, 6)
```

I want to do this in a loop but I also want control of the individual color bars.
How do I assign the return from `ax[].imshow()` to an array that I can reference later?

```
# 6 plots in one row
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,6)  
im0 = ax[0].imshow(data[:,:,0])
im1 = ax[1].imshow(data[:,:,1])
im2 = ax[2].imshow(data[:,:,2])
im3 = ax[3].imshow(data[:,:,3])
im4 = ax[4].imshow(data[:,:,4])
im5 = ax[5].imshow(data[:,:,5])
fig.colorbar(im5,extend='max')
```

Want this in a loop. How can I declare im[] as a type that will accept the return from `ax.imshow()`?

```
for i in np.arange(6):
  im[i] = ax[i].imshow(data[:,:,i])
fig.colorbar(im[5],extend='max')
``
```

Answer (score 1):

create an empty list and append the elements in your loop.

```
im = []
for i in np.arange(6):
  im.append(ax[i].imshow(data[:,:,i]))
fig.colorbar(im[5],extend='max')
```

could be simplified to a list comprehension (but this might be harder to read):

```
im = [ax[i].imshow(data[:,:,i]) for i in np.arange(6)]
```